# eTurboTouch does not work on Xubuntu Focal Fossa

Tags: touchscreen

I installed Xubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on an old Medion Akoya P4001 D (probably dates back to 2010).
Everything works fine, except the touchscreen; the system does not respond to me putting my finger on the screen.
I am sure there is no hardware problem;
I have seen the touchscreen work fine on the original OS (a custom Linux distro I had to discard),
as well as on an older Ubuntu version I had lying around (16.04 or 18.04, I don't remember).

I tried some terminal commands to dig up some info.

```
$ lsusb | grep -i touch
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 22b9:0008 eTurboTouch Technology, Inc. eTurboTouch
```

I searched for driver support on the manufacturer's site.
Seems totally outdated (Ubuntu 9.04, kernel 2.6); don't want to burn my hands on that.
http://www.eturbotouch.com/english/s_download_center.asp

Never mind, I've seen it work on an older Ubuntu distro, out of the box.
It *should* work without proprietary drivers.

```
$ sudo lsinput | grep -i touch -A4 -B5
/dev/input/event5
   bustype : BUS_USB
   vendor  : 0x22b9
   product : 0x8
   version : 257
   name    : "eTurboTouch eTurboTouch"
   phys    : "usb-0000:00:04.0.6/input0"
   uniq    : ""
   bits ev : (null) (null) (null) (null)
```

Now that we know the device, let's poll it.

```
$ sudo cat /dev/input/event5
```

Whenever I push the screen, I see binary data fill the screen. So it does work.
(OK, breaking out of the ongoing `cat` with Ctrl-C...)

```
$ sudo xinput list
```

I see a short list containing the other pointer and keyboard devices, but no touchscreen!

```
$ lsmod | grep -i 'hid\|touch\|dwav'
mac_hid                16384  0
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 57344  0
hid                   131072  2  usbhid,hid_generic
```

I read in a number of places that you'd need module `hid-multitouch`.
The module has been installed (`modinfo hid_multitouch` gives info),
but apparently `udev` did not feel the need to load it.

I was desperate enough to force-load the module.
I added a line `hid-multitouch` at the bottom of file `/etc/modules`.
I created a new file `/etc/rc.local` (it did not exist yet), made it executable,
and put in these lines (as suggested
[here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multitouch_displays) and
[here](https://chalk-elec.com/?p=2028)):

```
#!/bin/sh -e
echo 3 22b9 0008 1 > /sys/module/hid_multitouch/drivers/hid\:hid-multitouch/new_id
```

The `MT_CLASS` (1 in the line above) was a wild guess.
I also tried 3 (as that seemed to match the 'class' mentioned [here](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:22b9-0008)),
and 259 (because of the comment "eGalax Touchkit includes eTurboTouch CT-410/510/700" I read
[here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/input/touchscreen/usbtouchscreen.c)).

After reboot, module `hid-multitouch` was indeed loaded, but the touchscreen still played dead.

I checked the output of `dmesg` and `journalctl -b`, but could not find anything suspicious and touch-related there.

What should I do to make my touchscreen work as a pointer device on Xubuntu Focal Fossa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to be a good citizen, I did my research, and as often, solved my own problem in the process.
I posted my question (and this answer) anyway, hoping it may help some desperate soul (possibly myself) in the future.

The vital clue same from this command:

```
$ sudo libinput list-devices | head -n1
event5  - eTurboTouch eTurboTouch: libinput bug: missing tablet capabilities: btn-stylus resolution. Ignoring this device.
```

I googled the error message, and found out this wasn't the only touchscreen having this issue:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libinput/+bug/1772083

From the bug description:

```
*** Creating the following udev rules file, fixes the touchscreen for me ***
/etc/udev/rules.d/91-libinput-egalax-local.rules
ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="event[0-9]*", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="0eef", \
ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="0001", ENV{ID_INPUT_TABLET}="", ENV{ID_INPUT_TOUCHSCREEN}="1"
```

I adjusted it slightly to fit my situation.
I created a new file `/etc/udev/rules.d/91-libinput-eturbotouch-local.rules`
and put the following lines in:

```
ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="event[0-9]*", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="22b9", \
ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="0008", ENV{ID_INPUT_TABLET}="", ENV{ID_INPUT_TOUCHSCREEN}="1"
```

After a reboot, the touchscreen worked perfectly fine.

Notes:

- The vendor and model ID (`22b9` and `0008`, respectively) are based on the output of `lsusb`, as seen in the question.
- I rolled back my earlier changes to force-load `hid-multitouch`. The module is still not loaded by `udev`, but apparently, my touchscreen does not need it.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer! I just used it after upgrading my Medion Akoya P4001 D to Ubuntu 18.04. The touchscreen, which had still worked under 16.04, had stopped working. It now works fine again. So there is at least one desperate soul you helped.